# Transport of structure, why is $\left(G=(-1,1),* : (x,y) \to \frac{x+y}{1+xy}\right )$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, hyperbolic-functions

It is closely related to this topic:

[Prove that $x * y = \frac{x+y}{1+xy}$ is a stable part of $G=(-1, 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328260/prove-that-x-y-fracxy1xy-is-a-stable-part-of-g-1-1)

As proven, $*$ is an internal operation for $G$.
Plus one may observe that $\tanh$ is bijective from  $R$ to $G$ and $\tanh(x+y)=\tanh(x)*\tanh(y)$

I guess I am supposed to conclude that $G,*$ is a group but I do not see precisely how ? What theorem or property should be used ?

Comment: Just curious, what does $th(x)$ means?

Comment: sorry it is Hyperbolic Tangent tanh

Comment: This notation is occasionally used in france where I study (th instead of tanh). I changed for clarity

Comment: You might have a theorem somewhere in your notes explaining that if $(H,\cdot)$ is a group, $f:H\to G$ a bijection, and $\ast$ the composition law on $G$ uniquely defined by the fact that $f(x)\ast f(y)=f(x\cdot y)$ for every $x$ and $y$ in $H$, then $(G,\ast)$ is a group. Or, you can check the axioms one by one. Where is the trouble?

Comment: I have no such theorem, but i should definitely have thought of coming back to the axiom. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(G, *)$ is a group because it obeys the axioms of a group:

1. the operation $(G,*)$ has closure: what you call 'an internal operation'. But that is just the beginning; we also need:
2. it is associative:
   \begin{align} 
   (x*y)*z &= \left(\frac{x+y}{1+xy}\right)*z\\
   &= \frac{\frac{x+y}{1+xy}+z}{1 + \frac{x+y}{1 +xy}z}\\
   &= \frac{x+y+z(1+xy)}{1 + xy + (x+y)z}\\
   &= \frac{x+y+z + xyz}{1 + xy + xz + yz}\\
   &=\frac{x(1+yz) + y + z}{1 + yz + x(y+z)}\\
   &= \frac{x + \frac{y+z}{1 + yz}}{1 +x \frac{y+z}{1+yz}}\\
   &= x * \left(\frac{y+z}{1 + yz}\right)\\
   & = x * (y*z).
   \end{align}
3. there is an identity element in $G$: $\forall x\in G, x * 0 = \frac{x+0}{1+ x\cdot 0} = x$
4. every element has an inverse: for all $x \in G, \exists y \in G: x+y =0$. And $x+y=0 \implies x*y = 0$. So $\forall x \in G, \exists y \in G: x*y = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to prove this statement (thanks to @Did)

*If (H,⋅) is a group, f:H→G a bijection, and ∗ the composition law on G uniquely defined by the fact that f(x)∗f(y)=f(x⋅y) for every x and y in H, then (G,∗) is a group.*

Assume that 
just consider x,y,z this respective antecedent of a,b,c by f

1. **associativity**: a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c $\iff$ f(x)*f(y.z)=f(x.y)*f(z) $\iff$ f(x.(y.z))=f((x.y).z) which is obvious as (H,.) is a group.
2. **neutral existance**: f(z)=f(z* $0_H$ )=f(z)*f($0_H$) and f(z)=f($0_H$*z)=f($0_H$)*f(z) thus f($0_H$)=$0_G$ is neutral.
3. **inverse**: f(0_G)=f($x^{-1}$*x)=f($x^{-1}$)*a=$0_G$