# $(G,\circ)$ is an abelian group, where $x\circ y=\frac{x+y+a(1+xy)}{1+xy+a(x+y)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G=(-1,1)$ and $a\in G$ be fixed. Prove that $(G,\circ)$ is an abelian group, where $$x\circ y=\frac{x+y+a(1+xy)}{1+xy+a(x+y)}, \forall x,y\in G.$$

To me, it seems extremely tedious to prove the axioms of the group in this case. Proving associativity is horrendous and I don't believe that any other of the axioms (apart from commutativity) is provable without extremely long computations.

In order to avoid this, I tried to use the so-called structure transport i.e. finding a bijective function from $G$ to some well-known group. I couldn't come up with any function, so I don't know how to actually solve this question. I doubt that it can be solved by proving each of the group axioms, but if anyone finds a way to do this I would be both amazed and grateful.

Comment: According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5Ccirc%20y%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx%2By%2Ba(1%2Bxy)%7D%7B1%2Bxy%2Ba(x%2By)%7D%2C%20%5Cforall%20x%2Cy%5Cin%20G%24%2C%20abelian%20&p=1), this question is new to MSE.

Comment: There is a restriction:  $a \in G$.  But I'm having real trouble proving that there's an identity element under this operation.  I suspect that identifying the identity element might give some insight into what's going on.

Comment: The identity satisfies $e \circ e =e$. This gives $e=-a$. The formula then reminds me of automorphisms of the unit disk. These may be your structure transport.

Comment: $G=(-1,1)$ means open inteval $(-1,1)$ ?

Comment: @who Yes, it does

Comment: Then, i don't think it's correct.Take, $x=y=2-\sqrt{3},a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: @who I  took that and got $x \circ y \approx 0.836$?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг - me too: here's a wolframalpha link https://bit.ly/35FDDac

Comment: Setting $a=0$ to simplify makes this MSE question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328260/prove-that-x-y-fracxy1xy-is-a-stable-part-of-g-1-1) look useful

Comment: Oops!I applied a wrong formula, instead $tanh(x+y)$, i took $tan(x+y)$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the structure transport is the composition of two functions, first is hyperbolic tangent, as
$$ \tanh (x+y) = \frac{\tanh x + \tanh y}{1 + \tanh x \tanh y}.  $$
Second is the Mobius transformation 
$$ m(z) = \frac{z+a}{az+1}  $$

Note that $$  \frac{p+aq}{q+ap} = m\left(\frac{p}{q} \right)  $$

Works very nicely. Note that the group identity is $(-a).$ All we are doing is mapping the interval to itself by Mobius transformation, in such a way that $-a$ maps to $0.$ Then we use the known operation $ \frac{u+v}{1+uv} \; , \;  $ then back by the inverse of the Mobius transformation.

Comment: Readers unfamiliar with "structure transport" can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2004327/242)  (and its links) for examples of transporting algebraic structures along a bijection.

Comment: See also Northshield's delightful paper on the associativity of the secant methd linked [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1898116/242)